# A convergent sequence in $\ell^1$ and bounded sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X \subset \ell^1$ be a infinite, linearly independent subset of $\ell^1$ over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $V=\operatorname{span}(A)$

Let $\{v_m\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset V$ be a sequence of $V$ with
$$
\forall m \in \mathbb{N}: 
v_m = \sum_{j=1}^{L_m}
(a_{m,j} \cdot x_{m,j} )
$$
with $a_{m,j} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x_{m,j} \in X$ and $L_m$ is a finite integer

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R_+}$

Let $\forall m,j \in \mathbb{N}: \alpha < k_{m,j}< \beta$

Let
$$
\forall m \in \mathbb{N}:
u_m = \sum_{j=1}^{L_m}
((a_{m,j} \cdot k_{m,j}) \cdot x_{m,j} )
$$

My question is if is it true that
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty} v_m=v \in V
\Longrightarrow
\text{the sequence }
u_m
\text{ is bounded in $\ell^1$ metric}
$$

Thanks for any suggestion